# How to translate my android application?

Tags: android, translation

Hi all is there a way for me to translate my application to a different language and not to pay for others to translate it for me? I have seen in google play there is an option suggesting that I should upload my strings.xml file and they will translate it for me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your string values in res/values-XX where XX is the language code, but you have to translate by yourself.
Here's a list of languages code : http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php
Pick up one from "ISO 639-1 Code" column.

If you want to "upload" your string.xml on Google Play developer Console, you'll have to pay for it.

Comment: So just to make sure I understood correctly I create a new string.xml file with the name string-XX.xml in the same folder where the original string.xml is? Also how do I call it? how will my app know which string XML to load?

Comment: No, let's take an example. You want to translate in french. You put a string.xml file in res/values-fr/string.xml with the exact same content than in your res/values/string.xml, but you translate theses in french. In your layouts file, use @string/stringResourceName. In your java code use Context.getResources().getString(R.string.stringResourceName);

Comment: Ok i think I understood that thank you. But how can I set a condition for the translation. I mean can it be for example: if you are in China and you download the app the language displayed in the app is Chinese and not English? Because with the method getString()....etc I just call for the string.

Comment: It should automatically use the language the user of your app has set as its system language. If it's available, that is. And you set the name of your map correctly.

Comment: In fact, you don't have to deal with that. When you ask for a string value with getString() or with @string, android choose the language to pick. In you example, Android will detect : user is Chinese (the system language is, at least), so i'll give you values from res/values-cn/string.xml. So you don't have to precise which string you want.

Comment: Also, if the user language is not present in your values, android will pick values from res/values/string.xml, which is the default language.

Comment: LOL epic nice ... so I dont have to pay anything to Google if I translate it on my own?

Comment: If you speak the language, no, you don't. Bu I assume you're not a perfect speaker for every language in the world... So you might have to, depending on the situation :)

Comment: I just want it to be translated to only 1 language... my native language so I think I can handle that :D Thanks again for your help mate appreciate it!!! (bow)

Comment: Yeah if that's your native, easy :)